# Snapshot of SwiftUI view is partially cut off

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimage, ios15

I tried to create a `UIImage` from a SwiftUI view, a snapshot, with the code from [HWS: How to convert a SwiftUI view to an image](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image).

I get the following result, which is obviously incorrect because the image is cut-off.

[image: Result]

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var savedImage: UIImage?

    var textView: some View {
        Text("Hello, SwiftUI")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 100) {
                textView

                Button("Save to image") {
                    savedImage = textView.snapshot()
                }
            }

            if let savedImage = savedImage {
                Image(uiImage: savedImage)
                    .border(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the original view that is snapshot is lower down than it should be, but I'm not sure. How do I fix this?

---

#### Edits

We have discovered this problem does not occur on iOS 14, only iOS 15. So the question is... how can this be fixed for iOS 15?

Comment: It is because you are using ZStack there! The Image is placing itself on top of all Views!

Comment: @swiftPunk I know it's placing on top of all the views. But why is the snapshot offset from the correct place? The red rectangle outlines where it _should_ be filling.

Comment: Works fine for me (iPhone 12, iOS 14.5). Maybe try `.resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`?

Comment: @George: It works fine for me as well! look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYrlR.png

Comment: @aheze That has the same problem, but just the red border and the button just fit the screen.

Comment: @aheze Hmm... it works on iOS 14.4 simulator for me but not iOS 15. Doesn't work on real device with iOS 15 either. So some problem with iOS 15.

Comment: @swiftPunk What iOS version did you test on? (see above comment too)

Comment: I used iOS 14 with xCode 12.5.1 @George

Comment: This is exactly my problem as well, only iOS 15.x, iOS 14 works as expected.  Anyone have any fix yet?

Comment: @Rob Nope, not yet.

Comment: @George I just tried running it on the iOS 15.1 beta using xCode 13.0 and same problem there.

Comment: I just sent feedback to Apple Problem ID: FB9666959

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I also recently noticed this issue. I tested on different Simulators (for example, iPhone 8 and iPhone 13 Pro) and realized that the offset seems always half the status bar height. So I suspect that when you call `drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)`, internally SwiftUI always takes safe area insets into account.

Therefore, I modified the `snapshot()` function in your `View` extension by using the `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_:)` view modifier, and it worked:

```swift
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution and it worked for me!  I did keep the UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat portion of @claes solution too.  The .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top]) view modifier did the trick.

Comment: great solution.

Comment: Hey! Does it work in iOS 16? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in iOS 16

Comment: I'm getting this error: "drawing with afterScreenUpdates:YES inside CoreAnimation commit is not supported."

Answer (score 5):

The main thing that is necessary to avoid the extra whitespace is that the additional safe area insets should minus the original safe area insets

This is my current implementation and works to render views that are not on screen. Tested with iPhone 7 iOS 15.7 and iPhone 13 with iOS 16.2 beta, and iPad mini 6 with iOS 16.2 beta.

```
extension View {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        
        let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes 
        let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene 
        let window = windowScene?.windows.first
        
        window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        
        controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Int.max), width: 1, height: 1)
        controller.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -controller.view.safeAreaInsets.top, left: -controller.view.safeAreaInsets.left, bottom: -controller.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: -controller.view.safeAreaInsets.right)
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize      
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        controller.view.sizeToFit()
        
        let image = controller.view.asImage()
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        
        return image
    }
}
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage  {
   
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the time when Image came from URL using Kingfisher URL Image not save

Answer (score 1):

I also noted this annoying behaviour in iOS15 and think I found a workaround solution until the issue with iOS15 and `drawHierarchy(in: afterScreenUpdates:)` is solved.

This extension worked (tested on simulator iOS15.0 & iOS14.5 and iPhone XS Max iOS15.0.1) for me in my app, you can set the scale to higher than 1 if you need a higher resolution image:

```
extension View {
    func snapshotiOS15() -> UIImage {

        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
    
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = 1
        format.opaque = true
            
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
            
        let window = UIWindow(frame: view!.bounds)
        window.addSubview(controller.view)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: view!.bounds, format: format)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                view?.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

It turns out that the above solution only works if the `view` (to be saved as an `UIImage`) is embedded in a `NavigationView` for which the view modifier `.statusBar(hidden: true)` is added. See example code below to reproduce the result:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StartView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TestView()
        }.statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var testView: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .font(.system(size: 42.0))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            testView
            Button(action: {
                let imageiOS15   = testView.snapshotiOS15()
            }, label: {
                Text("Take snapshot")
                    .font(.headline)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not get this to work as it did for you.  The resulting image is still shifted and partially cut off.  I tried using the simulator iOS 15.0 and physical iPad running 15.1 beta 4.  Both seemed to have no change to before, unless I am missing something else you did to get it to work.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for testing it. Hmm.. strange. Re-tested and works in may app but let me see if it has something to do with my SwiftUI View

Comment: @Rob, I found the issue why it was working in my app. See the edit above.

Comment: I still can not reproduce a working work-a-round.  Maybe my swiftUI view is more complex.  The thing is this all works fine prior to iOS 15.x.

Comment: @Rob, have you tried the example code above? If so did it work for you? If not, could you produce some sample code where you experience the issue that I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

After **iOS 16** you can use **ImageRenderer** to export bitmap image data from a SwiftUI view.

Just keep in mind, you have to call it on the **main thread**. I used MainActor here. However, in this example, because it is firing from the Button action which is always on the main thread the MainActor is unnecessary.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var renderedImage = Image(systemName: "photo.artframe")
    @Environment(\.displayScale) var displayScale

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            renderedImage
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .background(.gray)
            
            Button("Render SampleView") {
                let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...100)
                let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: createSampleView(number: randomNumber))
                
                /// The default value of scale property is 1.0
                renderer.scale = displayScale
                
                if let uiImage = renderer.uiImage {
                    renderedImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor func createSampleView(number: Int) -> some View {
        Text("Random Number: \(number)")
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need Snapshot for ListView or Scrollview in swiftUI, use this class.

This is subclass `UIHostingViewController` can found here
https://gist.github.com/pabloruan0710/2c58f31767ff56d6949dbefa45ab6ced

```swift
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = HostSnapshoptViewController(rootView: self)
        let targetSize = controller.getSize()
        let bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        let window = UIWindow(frame: bounds)
        window.rootViewController = controller
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let image = controller.snapshot()
        return image
    }
}

extension UIView {
  func asImage() -> UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
    return renderer.image { rendererContext in
      layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
    }
  }
}
```